# Which accuracy should I trust? Model.Evaluate or Model.Predict?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, tensorflow2.0

Question: I am doing a multi-class image classification using TensorFlow 2.5 on Google Colab. I received three different values of classification accuracy and I do not know which one I should trust and why they are different.

Demonstration:

when I was **evaluating** on the test set, I received `accuracy_1`

29/29 [==============================] - 5s 147ms/step - loss: 1.1036 - accuracy: **0.3186**

when I was **predicting** on the test set, I received `accuracy_2`, which is **0.22**

```
          precision    recall  f1-score   support

       0       0.69      0.12      0.21      1305
       1       0.15      0.78      0.26       272
       2       0.14      0.13      0.13       231

accuracy                           0.22      1808
macro avg      0.33      0.34      0.20      1808
weighted avg   0.54      0.22      0.20      1808
```

Here's how I got `accuracy_3`, whose value is **0.2129424778761062**
:

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
prediction = np.argmax(detector.predict(test_dataset), axis=1)
accuracy_3 = accuracy_score(
    np.concatenate([label.numpy() for image, label in test_dataset.take(-1)]),
    prediction
))
```

I discovered that if I run the code block that calculates `accuracy_3` for multiple times. I get different result each time but they will differ much from `accuracy_2`, which is 0.22. Here is the code for the calculation of `accuracy_1` and `accuracy_2`:

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Callback

class Peek(Callback):

    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None):
      current_decayed_lr = self.model.optimizer._decayed_lr(tf.float32).numpy()
      print(f"Current learning rate: {current_decayed_lr}")

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
      print("Evaluating...")
      self.model.evaluate(test_dataset, verbose=1) # calculates accuracy_1
      print("Predicting...")
      predictions = np.argmax(self.model.predict(test_dataset), axis=1)
      true_categories = np.array([label.numpy() for image, label in test_dataset.unbatch()])
      print(classification_report(true_categories, predictions)) # calculates accuracy_2
```

The difference between `accuracy_2` and `accuracy_3` is more likely due to random chance but `accuracy_1` is much larger than the other two. I searched on stackoverflow and some posts say the difference could be due to `shuffle=True` in `ImageDataGenerator` when creating the test set. My case is different because I was not using `ImageDataGenerator` for performance's sake. I was loading data using TFRecords, here is the full code.

```
import os
import math
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from glob import glob
from progressbar import progressbar
from os.path import basename, exists
from tensorflow.sparse import to_dense
from tensorflow.data import Dataset, Options, TFRecordDataset
from tensorflow.image import decode_jpeg, encode_jpeg, resize
from tensorflow.train import Feature, Features, BytesList, Int64List, FloatList, Example
from tensorflow.io import read_file, TFRecordWriter, FixedLenFeature, VarLenFeature, parse_single_example
from tensorflow.data.experimental import AUTOTUNE

class DataLoader:

  def __init__(self, subset_name):
    self.subset_name = subset_name
    self.file_pattern = glob(
        f"./dataset/{self.subset_name}/**/*.jpg",
        recursive=True
    )
    self.target_size = (224, 224) 
    self.classes = [b"Negative", b"Positive", b"Unreadable"]
    self.n_images = len(self.file_pattern)
    self.n_shards = 32
    self.write_shard_size = math.ceil(1.0 * self.n_images / self.n_shards)
    self.read_shard_size = 64
    self.output_dir = f"tfrecords-jpeg-{subset_name}-{'x'.join(map(lambda x: str(x), self.target_size))}"

  def fetch_image_and_label(self, filename):
    bits = read_file(filename)
    image = decode_jpeg(bits)
    image = resize(image, self.target_size)
    height = tf.shape(image)[0]
    width = tf.shape(image)[1]
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.uint8)
    image = encode_jpeg(image, optimize_size=True, chroma_downsampling=False)
    label = tf.expand_dims(filename, axis=-1)
    label = tf.strings.split(label, sep="/")
    label = label.values[-2]
    return image, label, height, width
  
  @staticmethod
  def _bytestring_feature(list_of_bytestrings):
    return Feature(bytes_list=BytesList(value=list_of_bytestrings))

  @staticmethod
  def _int_feature(list_of_ints):
    return Feature(int64_list=Int64List(value=list_of_ints))
  
  @staticmethod
  def _float_feature(list_of_floats):
    return Feature(float_list=FloatList(value=list_of_floats))

  def to_tfrecord(self, tfrec_filewriter, img_bytes, label, height, width):
    class_num = np.argmax(np.array(self.classes) == label)
    one_hot_class = np.eye(len(self.classes))[class_num]
    feature = {
        "image": self._bytestring_feature([img_bytes]),
        "class": self._int_feature([class_num]),
        "label": self._bytestring_feature([label]),
        "size": self._int_feature([height, width]),
        "one_hot_class": self._float_feature(one_hot_class.tolist())
    }
    return Example(features=Features(feature=feature))

  def write_records(self):
    print(f"{self.n_images} images, {self.n_shards} shards with {self.write_shard_size} images each.")
    filenames = Dataset.list_files(self.file_pattern, seed=35155)
    dataset = filenames.map(self.fetch_image_and_label, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE).batch(self.write_shard_size)
    if not exists(self.output_dir):
      os.mkdir(self.output_dir)
    print("Writing TFRecords...")
    for shard, (image, label, height, width) in enumerate(dataset):
      shard_size = image.numpy().shape[0]
      filename = f"{self.output_dir}/{str(shard).zfill(2)}-{shard_size}.tfrec"
      with TFRecordWriter(filename) as out_file:
        for i in progressbar(range(shard_size)):
          example = self.to_tfrecord(
            out_file,
            image.numpy()[i],
            label.numpy()[i],
            height.numpy()[i],
            width.numpy()[i]
          )
          out_file.write(example.SerializeToString())
      print(f"Wrote file {filename} containing {shard_size} records")

  def _read_tfrecord(self, example):
    features = {
        "image": FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        "class": FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        "label": FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        "size": FixedLenFeature([2], tf.int64),
        "one_hot_class": VarLenFeature(tf.float32)
    }
    example = parse_single_example(example, features)
    image = decode_jpeg(example["image"], channels=3)
    image = tf.reshape(image, [*self.target_size, 3])
    class_num = example["class"]
    label = example["label"]
    height = example["size"][0]
    width = example["size"][1]
    one_hot_class = to_dense(example["one_hot_class"])
    # return image, class_num, label, height, width, one_hot_class
    # return only image and class_num because we're classifying images
    return image, class_num

  def read_records(self):
    from tensorflow.io.gfile import glob
    option_no_order = Options()
    option_no_order.experimental_deterministic = False
    filenames = glob(f"{self.output_dir}/*.tfrec")
    dataset = TFRecordDataset(filenames, num_parallel_reads=AUTOTUNE)
    dataset = dataset.with_options(option_no_order)
    dataset = dataset.map(self._read_tfrecord, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(10000)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
    dataset = dataset.batch(self.read_shard_size)
    return dataset

train_loader = DataLoader("train")
validation_loader = DataLoader("validation")
test_loader = DataLoader("test")
train_dataset = train_loader.read_records()
validation_dataset = validation_loader.read_records()
test_dataset = test_loader.read_records()
train_dataset = train_dataset.concatenate(validation_dataset)
```

The difference between `accuracy_2` and `accuracy_3` still exists and `accuracy_3` still changes every time I run the code block that computes `accuracy_3` even after `dataset = dataset.shuffle(10000)` is removed from `def read_records(self)` in `DataLoader` class.

I will also paste the code regarding how the model was instantiated and compiled to provide more background information.

```
from tensorflow.keras import Input, Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam
from tensorflow.keras.applications.densenet import DenseNet201
from tensorflow.keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dropout, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.applications.densenet import preprocess_input

def create_model():
  feature_extractor = DenseNet201(
      weights="imagenet",
      input_shape=(224, 224, 3),
      include_top=False
  )
  feature_extractor.trainable = True
  inputs = Input([224, 224, 3])
  x = preprocess_input(inputs)
  x = feature_extractor(x)
  x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
  x = Dense(32, activation="elu")(x)
  x = Dropout(0.8)(x)
  outputs = Dense(3, activation="softmax")(x)
  detector = Model(inputs, outputs)
  detector.compile(
      optimizer=SGD(learning_rate=0.001, momentum=0.9),
      loss=["sparse_categorical_crossentropy"],
      metrics=["sparse_categorical_accuracy"]
  )
  return detector

detector = create_model()

peek = Peek()
detector.fit(
    train_dataset,
    epochs=1,
    validation_data=test_dataset,
    class_weight=class_weight,
    callbacks=[peek],
)
```

Comment: I think you did shuffle: `dataset = dataset. shuffle(10000)`, for all data set whereas it should be only applied on the training set but not for validation and test set.

Comment: @M.Innat Even if I removed this line, the accuracy still changes. Do you have any idea why `accuracy_1` and `accuracy_2` are so different? I have a fair big test set (a few hundreds of images).